# sets many IE filters from Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

It's posssible to set many IE filters from JavaScript or jquery?

This sets only for one:

```
object.style.filter ="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=20)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put multiple filters in separate blocks. You have to put all filters in in single declaration.

Example:

```
object.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.MotionBlur(strength=50)
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2, mirror=1)";
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Search for "multiple" in this document.